# Error XFC0040 Cannot convert value to Microsoft.Maui.Thickness

Tags: xaml, maui

I have the ContentPage:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="NetMauiApp.LoginPage"
             Title="LoginPage">

    <Grid RowDefinitions="Auto,*,Auto">

        <!--Header-->
        <Grid>
            <!--header content-->
            <Image Source="topsiof.png" VerticalOptions="Start" Margin="0 -1 0 0" />
        </Grid>
```

I have the following error at compile time:
Error XFC0040 Cannot convert value "0 -1 0 0" to "Microsoft.Maui.Thickness".

However, I can remove the margin property to run my application and add it again when make debug without having any errors..

Why does this occur?

Comment: `Margin="0,-1,0,0"`  You are missing the commas.

Answer (score 1):

sample from the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/align-position?view=net-maui-8.0#position-controls) - note the use of commas

```
<StackLayout Padding="0,20,0,0">
  <!-- Margin defined by a single uniform value. -->
  <Label Text=".NET MAUI" Margin="20" />
  <!-- Margin defined by horizontal and vertical values. -->  
  <Label Text=".NET iOS" Margin="10,15" />
  <!-- Margin defined by four distinct values that are applied to the left, top, right, and bottom. -->  
  <Label Text=".NET Android" Margin="0,20,15,5" />
</StackLayout>
```

Comment: While this is indeed the accurate format, the key point of confusion lies in the behavior observed during debugging mode - even when updating a value with an incorrect format, the hot reload appears to function correctly.